# Setting up Lucee as a dev environment on Mac OS X with Tomcat

Tags: macos, tomcat, osx-elcapitan, lucee

I am having some trouble setting up Lucee on my Mac for a development environment. Lucee is running, as I am able to bring up the server admin page, but none of my development sites will process CFML. I have added the sites to the Tomcat server.xml file, so it will serve them, but Lucee doesn't seem to know they are there. What do I need to do to tell Lucee about these sites?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your environment? How did you install Lucee? Are you using a web server in addition to Lucee? How are you trying to access your sites now that they're listed in your server.xml file?

Comment: I finally found the answer in that I needed to update the web.xml file with information about Lucee. It wasn't in the Mac setup instructions on the Lucee site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it turns out that I needed to add the Lucee information to the Tomcat web.xml file. This wasn't in the Mac OSX Lucee setup documentation, but I found it elsewhere. Here is what was needed:

```
    <!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- Lucee CFML Servlet - this is the main Lucee servlet                   -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<servlet id="Lucee">
  <description>Lucee CFML Engine</description>
  <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet</servlet-class>
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- to specify the location of the Lucee Server config and libraries,   -->
  <!-- uncomment the init-param below.  make sure that the param-value     -->
  <!-- points to a valid folder, and that the process that runs Lucee has  -->
  <!-- write permissions to that folder.  leave commented for defaults.    -->
  <!--
  <init-param>
    <param-name>lucee-server-root</param-name>
    <param-value>/var/Lucee/config/server/</param-value>
    <description>Lucee Server configuration directory (for Server-wide configurations, settings, and libraries)</description>
  </init-param>
  !-->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- to specify the location of the Web Contexts' config and libraries,  -->
  <!-- uncomment the init-param below.  make sure that the param-value     -->
  <!-- points to a valid folder, and that the process that runs Lucee has  -->
  <!-- write permissions to that folder.  the {web-context-label} can be   -->
  <!-- set in Lucee Server Admin homepage.  leave commented for defaults.  -->
  <!--
  <init-param>
    <param-name>lucee-web-directory</param-name>
    <param-value>/var/Lucee/config/web/{web-context-label}/</param-value>
    <description>Lucee Web Directory (for Website-specific configurations, settings, and libraries)</description>
  </init-param>
  !-->
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.cfc</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.cfml</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/index.cfc/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/index.cfml/*</url-pattern>

  <!-- url-pattern>*.cfm/*</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.cfml/*</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.cfc/*</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern !-->
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- Lucee REST Servlet - handles Lucee's RESTful web services             -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<servlet id="RESTServlet">
  <description>Lucee Servlet for RESTful services</description>
  <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>lucee.loader.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```